# Alerting the SAS Index Corruption

Tags: sas

Can any one please tell me if there is any way to create a Alert in SAS when index in the SAS system gets corrupted?

i could see we can create the Alert to identify the Index performance and below is the source.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mdsug/65072/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1sjhliteljcoan1nwmv2dos56fd.htm

But my requirement is alert should be trigger when the index gets corrupted.

Comment: Your question seems to relate to indexes in the database sense, but that link is about model performance indices. Which one are you interested in?

Comment: What kind of alert are you looking for? An email? Text message?